getLastKnownLocation() entrega null si cambio de aplicación
Estoy capturando la ubicación mediante un servicio cada X minutos con un timerTask, lo cual funciona bien, pero solo si tengo la aplicación en foco: si la minimizo o si cambio de aplicación getLastKnownLocation() me devuelve null.
He intentado hacerlo en el mainActivity con el timerTask, dentro de un servicio, y he intentado usando el GPS el Network.

Soy nuevo en android por lo que ya no sé qué más hacer.

locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(getGPSprovider(),locationListener,Looper.getMainLooper());
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(getGPSprovider());
if (location!=null) {
    lat = location.getLatitude();
    lon = location.getLongitude();
    Log.d("LAT",String.valueOf(lat));
    Log.d("LON",String.valueOf(lon));
} else {
    lat = (double) 0;
    lon = (double) 0;
}


Lo intente con fusedLocationCliente y me sucede lo mismo, latitud y longitud 0, al volver a la app vuelve a entregarme los valores correctos y el servicio funciona bien cada X segundos.
'''fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(ubicacionReal.this);
fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(location -> '''

Edita la pregunta y agrega todo lo que te refieres con He probado de todo. Saludos.

El problema que comentas, en realidad es un funcionamiento que puede considerarse "normal", ya que cuando trabajas con servicios de geolocalización en segundo plano en Android, a  partir de Android 8 (API nivel 26), se tienen nuevas restricciones lo cual puede afectar la capacidad de acceder a la ubicación cuando la app no está en foco (primer plano), ya que puede suspender algunos servicios y en este caso se provocaría que al obtener el valor de getLastKnownLocation() obtengas un valor null.
Primero asegura tener los permisos correctos en el archivo AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Debes requerir los permisos manualmente, a partir de Android 10 (API 29), es necesario el permiso ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION para obtener la ubicación en segundo plano.
Debes usar FusedLocationProviderClient, ya que es lo recomendado por estar optimizada para obtener la geolocalización
Para obtener la Geolocalización usando LocationRequest:
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
...
...
...

LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
locationRequest.setInterval(30000);  //* Geolocalización cada 30 segundos.
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);  //* Intervalo de petición cada 5 segundos.
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY); 

LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Log.d("Geolocalizacion", "Latitud: " + String.valueOf(latitude));
                Log.d("Geolocalizacion", "Longitud: " + String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        }
    }
};

De esta forma se iniciaría la petición de la geolocalización:
fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());


Gracias Jorgesys, probe con el método que me indicas y se me produce el mismo problema, saco la app de foco o el equipo suspende y inmediatamente dejo de obtener la ubicación.

Y realmente necesito mantener enviando la ubicación para poder terminar la app. Soy nuevo en android y he buscado por internet y sigo con el mismo problema. Gracias.

Finalmente encontré la causa, al solicitar los permisos android actualmente solo da 3 opciones "mientras la APP está en uso", "Solo esta vez" y "No permitir". La opción permitir siempre se debe hacer manualmente en los permisos de la aplicación y marcar "Siempre". Con eso se soluciona. Gracias.

@PatricioAburto Como comento en mi respuesta "Debes requerir los permisos manualmente", son necesarios de otra forma no podrás hacer uso de los permisos de Geolocalización. El usuario actualmente debe aceptar el permiso.
